# Atributo chega nulo no ManagedBean

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Tenho um objeto chamado HistoricoSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline, esse objeto tem algumas datas, uma descrição e outro objeto, chamado SituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline. As datas estão sendo salvas normalmente, entretanto a descrição e o SituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline, não estão sendo salvos, eles estão vindo como nulo

**Método que salva a análise da Documentação**

```
public void inserirAnaliseDocumentacaoOnline() throws ParseException {
    historicoSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline.setDataSituacao(new Date()); 
    Calendar prazo = Calendar.getInstance();
    prazo.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    historicoSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline.setPrazoRegularizacao(prazo.getTime());
    historicoSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline.setSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline(situacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnlineSelecionada);
    historicoSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline.setProtocolo(protocolo);
    historicoSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline.setDescricao(descricaoHistoricoSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline);

    historicoSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnlineDao.salvar(historicoSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline);
    enviarEmailParaProfissional(historicoSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline);

    historicoSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline = new HistoricoSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline();
}
```

**Classe Converter**

```
@FacesConverter(value="situacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnlineConverter")
public class SituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnlineConverter implements Converter {

@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String string) {
    if (string == null || string.equals("Selecione...")) {
        return null;
    }

    Long id = Long.parseLong(string);
    SituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline situacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline = new SituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline();
    situacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline.setIdSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline(id);

    return situacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline;
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object object) {
    if (object == null) {
        return null;
    }

    if(object instanceof SituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline) {
        SituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline situacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline = (SituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline) object;

        return "" + situacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline.getIdSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline();
    } 

    else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("object:" + object + "of type:" + 
                object.getClass().getName() + "; expected type:br.org.web.entities.SituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline");
    }
}    
}
```

**Entidade HistoricoSituacaoProtocoloOnline**

```
@Entity
public class HistoricoSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Long idHistoricoSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline;
private Protocolo protocolo;
private SituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline situacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline;
private Date dataSituacao;
private Date prazoRegularizacao;
private String descricao;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public Long getIdHistoricoSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline() {
    return idHistoricoSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline;
}

public void setIdHistoricoSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline(Long idHistoricoSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline) {
    this.idHistoricoSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline = idHistoricoSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline;
}

@ManyToOne
public Protocolo getProtocolo() {
    return protocolo;
}

public void setProtocolo(Protocolo protocolo) {
    this.protocolo = protocolo;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "idSituacaoDocumentacaoProtcoloOnline")
public SituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline getSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline() {
    return situacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline;
}

public void setSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline(SituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline situacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline) {
    this.situacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline = situacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline;
}

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
public Date getDataSituacao() {
    return dataSituacao;
}

public void setDataSituacao(Date dataSituacao) {
    this.dataSituacao = dataSituacao;
}

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
public Date getPrazoRegularizacao() {
    return prazoRegularizacao;
}

public void setPrazoRegularizacao(Date prazoRegularizacao) {
    this.prazoRegularizacao = prazoRegularizacao;
}

@Lob
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.StringClobType")
public String getDescricao() {
    return descricao;
}

public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
    this.descricao = descricao;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 3;
    hash = 31 * hash + (this.idHistoricoSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline != null ? this.idHistoricoSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final HistoricoSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline other = (HistoricoSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline) obj;
    if (this.idHistoricoSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline != other.idHistoricoSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline && (this.idHistoricoSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline == null || !this.idHistoricoSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline.equals(other.idHistoricoSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "HistoricoSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline{" + "idHistoricoSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline=" + idHistoricoSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline + ", "
            + "protocolo=" + protocolo + ", situacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline=" + situacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline + ", "
            + "dataSituacao=" + dataSituacao + ", prazoRegularizacao=" + prazoRegularizacao + ", descricao=" + descricao + '}';
}
}
```

**Entidade SituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline**

```
@Entity
public class SituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Long idSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline;
private String descricao;



public SituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline() {
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public Long getIdSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline() {
    return idSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline;
}

public void setIdSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline(Long idSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline) {
    this.idSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline = idSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline;
}

@Lob
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.StringClobType")
public String getDescricao() {
    return descricao;
}

public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
    this.descricao = descricao;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 7;
    hash = 29 * hash + (this.idSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline != null ? this.idSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final SituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline other = (SituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline) obj;
    if (this.idSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline != other.idSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline && (this.idSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline == null || !this.idSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline.equals(other.idSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "SituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline{" + "idSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline=" + idSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline + ", "
            + "descricao=" + descricao + '}';
}
}
```

**View que Salva o Objeto**

```
<h:form>
        <p:dialog widgetVar="analiseDocumentacaoDialog" header="Inserir Análise da Documentação">
        <h:outputLabel value="Situação da Documentação: "/>
        <br />

        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{protocoloController.situacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnlineSelecionada}"
                         converter="situacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnlineConverter"
                         validator="#{protocoloController.validatorTesteSituacao}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{protocoloController.obterSituacoesDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline()}" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>

        <br />

        <h:outputLabel value="Descrição da Situação: " />

        <br />

        <h:inputTextarea value="#{protocoloController.descricaoHistoricoSituacaoDocumentacaoProtocoloOnline}" cols="53" rows="7"
                         validator="#{protocoloController.validatorTesteDescricao}"/>
        <br />
        <p:commandButton action="#{protocoloController.inserirAnaliseDocumentacaoOnline()}" process="@this" 
                         update="#{protocoloController.atualizarComponentes}"
                         value="Inserir Analise" icon="inserir" oncomplete="analiseDocumentacaoDialog.hide()"/>

    </p:dialog>
    </h:form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No CommandButton para inserir a analise de documentacao online vc está definindo o process="@this" e está processando apenas o Button. Tente alterar para process="@form".

Comment: Era isso mesmo, obrigada!